# Pandas to have one row per email

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following table,  Peter and Halla,

```
Name    Age occupation  BillingContactEmail
Peter   44  Salesman    a@a.com
Andy    43  Manager a@a.com
Halla   33  Fisherman   b@b.com
```

how to make pandas to contain

```
Name    Age occupation  BillingContactEmail
Peter   44  Salesman    a@a.com
Halla   33  Fisherman   b@b.com
```

where we only contain an instance for an email? (meaning we will have distinct email in the end)

Comment: Look at `remove_duplicates()`.

Comment: You should be more specific about what criterion you want to use to decide which one to keep.  The first seen with that email?  The oldest?  Etc.

Answer (score 4):

use `drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['BillingContactEmail'])

    Name  Age occupation BillingContactEmail
0  Peter   44   Salesman             a@a.com
2  Halla   33  Fisherman             b@b.com
```

---

Addressing @DSM's comment

> You should be more specific about what criterion you want to use to decide which one to keep. The first seen with that email? The oldest? Etc.

By default, `drop_duplicates` keeps the first instance found.  This is equivalent to

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['BillingContactEmail'], keep='first')
```

However, you could also specify to keep the last instance via `keep='last'`

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['BillingContactEmail'], keep='last')

    Name  Age occupation BillingContactEmail
1   Andy   43    Manager             a@a.com
2  Halla   33  Fisherman             b@b.com
```

Or, drop all duplicates

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['BillingContactEmail'], keep=False)

    Name  Age occupation BillingContactEmail
2  Halla   33  Fisherman             b@b.com
```